# I want to write a code that opens a pdf document from a specified cell and saves it into a folder

Tags: vba, pdf

I've really been struggling with this project. The goal is to look at a cell and search for a PDF with that name, before saving a copy into a new folder with a new name from another cell. I've been trying to piece together how to open a PDF and then save it but honestly I'm not even sure I'm on the right track. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub GetFilePath_Click()

Dim FileAndLocation As Variant
Dim strPathLocation As String
Dim strFilename As String
Dim strPathFile As String
Dim StrFilename2 As String
strPathFile = "U:\Common\Product Mgt - RINC\KIC\CHCS LTC\Policy Forms"



strPathLocation = "U:\Common\Product Mgt - RINC\KIC\CHCS LTC\Policy Forms"



StrFilename2 = strPathLocation & strFilename


End Sub

strFilename = Worksheets("Pol. Form Batch Print").Range("e27").Value



Sub OpenPDF1()
Dim pdf As Object
Dim strPDF As String

Set pdf = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")

'pdf file to open
strPDF = "U:\Common\Product Mgt - RINC\KIC\CHCS LTC\Duplicate Policy Pages" & "E28"

'open the pdf file
pdf.Open strPDF
End Sub
'Sub OpenPDF()
'Dim a As String
'Dim myShell As Object
'Dim Filename As String
'a = ActiveCell.Value
'Set myShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'myShell.Run "U:\Common\Product Mgt - RINC\KIC\CHCS LTC\Duplicate Policy Pages" & "E28"
'End Sub
Sub Save_PDf()
Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
Set avdoc = AcroApp.GetActiveDoc


Dim PDSSaveCopy As Object



If Not (avdoc Is Nothing) Then





Set Pddoc = avdoc.GetPDDoc

WasSaved = Pddoc.Save(PDSaveFull, "U:\Common\Product Mgt - RINC\KIC\CHCS LTC\Duplicate Policy Pages")


Pddoc.Save PDSaveFull, "E27" & "U:\Common\Product Mgt - RINC\KIC\CHCS LTC\Duplicate Policy Pages"" & Sh1.Cells(e + 28, 1).Value &  .Endif """


End If





End Sub
```

Comment: You have a line of code between your 2 subs, so there's no way that would even compile (assuming you are using `Option Explicit`). Can you please clean it up a bit? Or are you just not sure where that line of code is supposed to go?

Comment: Why do you need to open the pdf if you are not doing anything with it (not editing). Just make a copy without opening and then rename it

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this:

here you read pdf file name in E27 cell, and save it with the name given in E28 cell.

```
Option Explicit

Sub OpenPDF1()
  Dim pdf As Object
  Dim strPDF As String

  Set pdf = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")

  'pdf file to open
  strPDF = "U:\Common\Product Mgt - RINC\KIC\CHCS LTC\Duplicate Policy Pages\" & Worksheets("Pol. Form Batch Print").Range("E27").Value

  'open the pdf file
  pdf.Open strPDF
End Sub

Sub Save_PDf()
  Dim AcroApp As Object, avdoc As Object, Pddoc As Object
  Dim PDSSaveCopy As Object
  
  Dim WasSaved As Long
 
  Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
  Set avdoc = AcroApp.GetActiveDoc



  If Not (avdoc Is Nothing) Then
    Set Pddoc = avdoc.GetPDDoc
    'WasSaved = Pddoc.Save(PDSaveFull, "U:\Common\Product Mgt - RINC\KIC\CHCS LTC\Duplicate Policy Pages")


    Pddoc.Save PDSaveFull, "U:\Common\Product Mgt - RINC\KIC\CHCS LTC\Duplicate Policy Pages\" & Worksheets("Pol. Form Batch Print").Range("E28").Value


  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: So far this is really helpful, but for some reason it's still not working. Is there any way to see why it's running but not doing anything? I've tried debugging it and everything seems to be in order